# C# Playing a sound in the background

Tags: c#, background

```
    private System.Media.SoundPlayer sp;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.main);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Play();
    }
```

main is a MP3 from resources...I get the following errors:
*The best overloaded method match for System.Media.SoundPlayer.SoundPlayer(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments

and

*cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft do a great tutorial on this!

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for wav.

```
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    player.Stream = Properties.Resources.main;
    player.Play();
```

Or this for MP3:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.URL = "main.mp3";
 wplayer.Controls.Play();
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.IO.Stream' at player.stream line

Comment: Very strange. Is your sound file a .wav? Where is the file located, in resources? Have uou added the Using for media?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play some SOUNDS in your Dot Net(C#,Vb.net) Form. Then write this code in your project and it will play a SOUND during execution. Remember you should have a **".wave"**  file for this purposes.

```
  using System.Media;  // write this at the top of the Form

   SoundPlayer my_sound = new SoundPlayer("F:/aeroplantakeover.wave"); //put your own .wave file path
   my_sound.Play();
```